# Python: web scraping: need help scraping a particular link or automating a button click

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I would like to download several specific sequences of DNA from a database. (http://medicago-mutant.noble.org/mutant/FNBline1.php?id=NF-FN+8113) 
I can easily parse the static links on that page, to follow them, but from the next page I cannot get the link to the file I'd like to download (http://gb.sc.noble.org/cgi-bin/gb2/gbrowse/medicago3_5/?name=CHR02FS001028027) it is under the "Go" button. Is there a way to get that information, or to automate the pushing of that button? 
The button triggers a javascript, opens a new window and immediately starts the download of the file.
I've been using urllib2 to download the sites, but it doesn't seem to make any sense to parse that source code for links.

Comment: What are you using for scraping? (Scrapy, etc?) That will help clarify what tools you're looking for help with, or if you're open to switching libraries.

Comment: I use the urllib2 module, but I am absolutely open to any solution.

Comment: Also, do you know if the "Go" button opens a new window, starts the download immediately, triggers a JavaScript event, etc? Any additional information about what you're currently using (eg urllib2) and what specific problem you're running into would be ideal to include in the question, in order to facilitate anybody who may be able to help. As it stands, the question runs the risk of being too open-ended for results.

Comment: PS: Fixing the 2nd link should help as well, good catch. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, does the website provide a link to download a tar ball of all the files?

I have no experience with urllib2, but in my experience selenium (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) should be able to do it pretty easily. Just open Selenium IDE (a browser plugin) and record the ID of the link you want to download, and use python to automate it. The selenium website provides detailed instructions (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/). You can also search on SO as there are a lot of answers here.

There are also many other tools such Watir, Sahi, WatiN, etc. You can find an incomplete list here: [Web Automation Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531718/web-automation-tool)  and here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_testing_tools.